# Anti-Bot comment system - PHP

Tags: php

> #### Update:
>
> Question posted at **CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/anti-bot-comment-system**

With some advice from SO [see the details on my previous questions if you are interested] i developed the system, which i think is quite strong for bot to automatically post comment !
I'm posting my code so you can view it and post some valuable comments !!
Any kind of constructive suggestion is welcome :)

`index.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function main()
{
 var str=$("#key").load("getToken.php",function (responseText) {
                                                 $("#key").val(responseText);
                                               }
      );
 setTimeout("main()", 100000);
}
</script>
</head>
 <body onload='main()'>
 <form name="f" action="poster.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="key" id="key" value=""/><br>
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`getToken.php`

```
<?php
 $key=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $hash=sha1($key.'mySecretKey');
 echo $key.'#'.$hash;
?>
```

`poster.php`

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['key']))
 exit;

$parts = explode('#',$_POST['key'],2);
$key = $parts[0];
$hash = $parts[1];

$date1 = $key;
$date2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)); 
$years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
$months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); 
$days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
$hours   = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60)); 
$minuts  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60); 
$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60)); 

if ($seconds < 5)
 echo $seconds.' Too fast, must be a naughty bot <br>';
else if ($seconds>5 && $seconds < 600)
 echo $seconds.' In time <br>';
else
 echo $seconds.' time out <br>';

if ($hash == (sha1($key.'sou')))
 echo $_POST['text'];
else
 echo 'You are a bot !';
?>
```

Comment: I'm also asking for any constructive suggestion

Comment: Is this enough $seconds = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);  to get the seconds?

Comment: Before giving a nice **CLOSE VOTE** please put your comment why you think this should be closed ? I'm not asking you to code for me and btw this code is running, I AM ASKING FOR ANY NEW IDEA, IMPROVEMENT

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic. There's a new [codereview stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for just these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Sander Marechal thanks for putting the reason, but i'm asking for Idea [i just put the code to share what i've made]

Comment: you should link to the previous question you are speaking about. I do not know what the purpose is!

Answer (score 2):

It's being closed since SO is not about code review or improvement. There is another [SE site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that.

As for the code: `365*60*60*24` should be a constant.

You should really improve your variable naming.

```
$date2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

`date2`? Does that say anything? `currentTime` is more like it. *Always* describe what variables contain, not what they are.

Comment: +1 because you reviewed it anyway

Comment: @jgauffin please delete your answer, i want to delete this question !

Comment: why? imho it still adds value to SO. a) It shows what kind of questions not to ask. b) It shows where to ask these kind of questions.

Comment: Oh yeah, u r right, but SO should put a codereview link in the footer

Comment: suggest that at http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90362/where-can-i-post-code-for-others-to-review i tried

Comment: If you got that answer, why did you still post the question at SO and not at CR?